# Mocking It.Is<> runs the comparison check twice when it parameters do not match

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have been experimenting creating unit test wrappers and comparison extensions - but i came across a problem.

I created an extension method which verifies that the value passed to the mock is correct (it will compare complex objects to make sure all the properties match.)
When it returns true, all is ok.
When it return false (the input was not correct), it is evaluated twice.

Is this expected behaviour? 
I couldn't see anything in the docs about why it would do it.

Simplest example i could replicate:

```
public interface ISomeTest
{
    bool RunTest(int i);
}

public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static int count = 0;
    public static bool CheckInputCorrect(this int o, int valueToCompareAgainst)
    {
        count++;
        if (valueToCompareAgainst == o)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class SomeTests
{
    [Test]
    public void TestWithMoq()
    {
        Mock<ISomeTest> mock = new Mock<ISomeTest>();
        mock.Setup(c => c.RunTest(It.Is<int>(p => p.CheckInputCorrect(2)))).Returns(true).Verifiable();

        ISomeTest someTest = mock.Object;

        someTest.RunTest(1);

        //fails
        Assert.AreEqual(1, MyExtensions.count);
    }
}
```

any ideas why?

Comment: The test passes.

Comment: Not for me - i'v ran the code in VS2019 / .net framework 4.7.2 and it fails

Comment: I'm in VS2019 in .net core 2.2

Comment: What version of Moq?

Comment: @OwenPauling I've tried it with the latest (4.11.0)

Comment: I've tried some different versions. It breaks in 4.8 onwards. If you run the test in 4.7.145 or lower it passes.